ASP.NET Core MVC: How to remove automatic encoding of html tags?
The program gets text with html tags from the SQLite database, then the text is displayed to the user in the browser. The tags are supposed to be automatically converted to html, but instead the tags are simply encoded.The tags in the line are displayed correctly, but when the application is launched, the tags are encoded
The end result is this: As a result, html tags are displayed as plain text.
Can you tell me how to make the browser convert tags?

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

See also the microsoft documentation for this issue.

ASP.NET Core MVC provides an HtmlString class which isn't automatically encoded upon output. This should never be used in combination with untrusted input as this will expose an XSS vulnerability.


if using this anyway, OP should consider using sandboxed iframe.  (that way you can turn off scripting/cross domain calls, etc..)  It'll help a bit with XSS vulnerabilities....
